# Android Media Player:setDataSource Failed

Tags: android

I try to create Media Player using Surface View.  When I try to set the DataSource for the Media Player, I got the setDataSource Failed Exception.  How to resolve it?

### Code:

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse("android.resource//"+getPackageName()+ "/raw/"+R.raw.androidvideo));
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mediaPlayer.release();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add colon after resource.

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+ "/raw/"+R.raw.androidvideo));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + R.raw.androidvideo));
```

Try this